# how to resize form inside popover dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a bootstrap navbar which have a button to trigger a popover with form inside, but the content of the form is too small

[image: look like this]

> my question is  how to resize, the popover?
>
> 1. this is my code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://snipplicious.com/css/font-awesome-4.1.0.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
        
    </head>
    <body class="body">
       <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand text-uppercase" href="#">Bukuwow <span class="label label-success text-capitalize">Free</span></a>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                           
                <!-- Start of pop over -->
                
                <li class="dropdown">
<!--                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn btn-circle dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign in</button>-->
                    <a href="#" id="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">the pop over link</a>
                    <div id="popover-head" class="hide"><strong>BUKUWOW</strong></div>
                    <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
                        
                         <form id="loginform" method="post" action="index.php" class="form">
                             
                                    <h5><strong>Login</strong></h5>
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username" size="20" maxlength="100">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></span>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" size="20" maxlength="100">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input class="btn-default btn-sm" id="loginbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">
                                     
                                </form>
                       
                    </div>
                </li>
              <!-- End of pop over -->
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
           
    
  
</div>
```

> 2. and this is my java script

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#popover').popover({ 
                    html : true,
                    title: function() {
                      return $("#popover-head").html();
                    },
                    content: function() {
                      return $("#popover-content").html();
                    }
                });
        });
```

**UPDATE**

when i inspect element, it seem i had two pop over??(you can see 2 BUKUWOW on there)

> 3. here is what i got from firebug

```html
<li class="dropdown">
<a id="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" href="#" data-original-title="" title="" aria-describedby="popover115502">the pop over link</a>
<!-- START this is the code which not exist in my actual code -->
<div id="popover115502" class="popover fade bottom in" role="tooltip" style="width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 0px; display: block;">
<div class="arrow" style="left: 50%;"></div>
<h3 class="popover-title">
<strong>BUKUWOW</strong>
</h3>
<div class="popover-content">
<form id="loginform" class="form" action="index.php" method="post">
<h5>
<div class="form-group ">
<div class="form-group">
<input id="loginbutton" class="btn-default btn-sm" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END this is the code which not exist in my actual code -->
<div id="popover-head" class="hide">
<strong>BUKUWOW</strong>
</div>
<div id="popover-content" class="hide" style="width: 300px;">
<form id="loginform" class="form" action="index.php" method="post">
<h5>
<div class="form-group ">
<div class="form-group">
<input id="loginbutton" class="btn-default btn-sm" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</li>
```

> 4. and this is my actual code

```html
<li class="dropdown">
<!--                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn btn-circle dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign in</button>-->
                    <a href="#" id="popover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">the pop over link</a>
                    <div id="popover-head" class="hide"><strong>BUKUWOW</strong></div>
                    <div style="width: 300px;" id="popover-content"  class="hide">
                        
                         <form id="loginform" method="post" action="index.php" class="form">
                             
                                    <h5><strong>Login</strong></h5>
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username" size="20" maxlength="100">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></span>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" size="20" maxlength="100">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input class="btn-default btn-sm" id="loginbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">
                                     
                                </form>
                       
                    </div>
                </li>
```

As you can see, in code number 3, it looks i had 2 form, but in my actual code (number 4) i only have 1 form

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given seem not enough for me to test the result. However I will try answering your question.

I am assuming your CSS class "hide" have the style "display: none;" and will get "display: initial;" from jQuery by clicking the button "the pop-over link".

```
<!-- your HTML file -->
<div style="width: 300px;" id="popover-content" class="hide">
<!-- Your form goes here -->
</div>
```

or

```
/*CSS file*/
#popover-content{width: 300px;}
```

This two method is just add a fixed width to the popover frame (By inline CSS or external CSS). The width is editable by yourself. Remind that this style should not add to class "hide", which will affect all element in class "hide".

Hope this can help you ;)

Comment: hello @Wing Choy, thanks for your help, i already update my question on above ^^